# Google map api & tparkin point-in-poly

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have been working on this site for about a week now. It isnt great but then again I am not great the web design. Any tips on improvements would be greatly appreciated.

Moving on I am having a problem with point in polygon extension that [tparkin](https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon) wrote for the google maps api. I have read through the read me, other post and everything but I can figure out why I keep getting this error ...

```
a.lat is not a function
    [Break On This Error] Ba(I,function(a){return!a?k:this.Z[xb]...{return new Q(this.Z.d,this.aa.d,i)};
```

I think it might be a problem with me using the functionality of tparkins extension incorrectly but like I said I cant figure out it.

Any help is greatly appreciated in advance.

This is the website with the script problem. Please let me know if you need any additional information.
[my website.](http://ec2-107-20-112-0.compute-1.amazonaws.com/)

Comment: Can't reproduce. I do not get this error on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem I was having. Check it out.

```
function codeAddress() {
 var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
 geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
   map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: results[0].geometry.location
   });
   var isWithinPolygon = polygon85.containsLatLng(results[0].geometry.location);
   alert(isWithinPolygon);
  } 
  else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
```

}

So the issues before was that instead of passing the coordinates results[0].geometry.location, I was passing it just location. Its a simple case of me not fully understanding what I was working with. Thank you for everyone that looked into this and sorry I wasted your time.

--Zac

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution - you should mark it as correct (click the checkbox), which will close the question.